# How to grant or revoke LIBRARYADMAUTH authority in DB2

Tags: db2

I know that LIBRARYADMAUTH is for future use but since it's a requirement so, is there any way to grant or revoke this to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If you see in the documentation for a catalog view "for future use", then it means that there was some planning but no use yet. Catalog structures can only change on major versions, so sometimes new fields are put in "just in case". If you would be able to grant a privilege, then it would be documented as part of the [GRANT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html) statements.

See this [blog entry about a guided tour of the Db2 catalog](https://blog.4loeser.net/2017/08/db2-catalog-guided-tour.html).